# Treat whitespace as text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, markdown, scintilla

Editing markdown tables in Notepad++ is a pain because whitespace is 'tied' to the word in front of it. That means you can't use Ctrl+Backspace or Ctrl+L/R navigation to edit whitespace because the preceding word gets caught up in your selection.

Is there any way to change Notepad++ to recognize both sides of a word as a selection boundary? I'm aware the Scintilla [keymap is editable](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Moving_And_Selecting_Around), but the word boundary side appears to be an either/or situation.

*Just some example markdown table:*

```
| Precipitation_Tot | mm        | total |   1   | Precipitation     | mm        | liquid precipitation |
| amb_press_Avg     | kPa       | mean  |   2   | AirPressure       | kPa       | barometric pressure
| PAR_density       | umol/(s m^2) | mean |   2   | PAR        | umol m^-2 s^-2 | photosynthetically active radiation (PAR) |
| batt_volt         | Vdc       | mean  |   2   | BatteryVoltage    | Volts DC  | system input voltage |
| panel_tmpr        | degC      | mean  |   2   | LoggerTemperature | Degrees C | logger panel temperature |
| std_wnd_dir       | degrees   | stdev |   -   | - | - | standard deviation of wind direction |
| VPD_air           | kPa       | mean  |   -   | - | - | vapor pressure deficit |
| Rn_meas           | W/m^2     | mean  |   -   | - | - | net radiation |
```